# awk unix insert into file location directory

Tags: linux, unix, awk

In linux, I am trying to select a variable from a specific column and row of CSV file and then use this variable as the end of a file location hierarchy.  When I type the following into a bash terminal window, it seems to work by outputting the variable in correct row and column on screen.

```
awk -F "," 'FNR == 2 {print $8}' /sdata/images/projects/ASD_SSD/1/ruths_data/ruth/imaging\ study/imaging\ study\ working/delete2.csv
```

However, I am trying to go do the following substitution within a script, this fails to work...

```
r=2
c=8
```

```
s=awk -F "," 'FNR == $r {print $c}' /sdata/images/projects/ASD_SSD/1/ruths_data/ruth/imaging\ study/imaging\ study\ working/delete2.csv
```

I then try to use the s output as the end of a hierarchy file location.  For example, /home/ork/js/s*

I keep getting the following error, so this looks like it's not creating the `s` variable and then not inserting it into the actual file location.

> omitting directory `/home/ork/js/'

I have spent a few hours trying to figure out what is preventing this from working and am a new user (so I am sure it is something simple, sorry).

I hope I was clear enough, please let me know if this requires further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question here. The single quotes are protecting the variables from the shell, so they never get expanded. Also command substitution is needed when assigning to variable `s`. One way to do it would be:

```
s=$(awk -F, 'FNR==r{print c}' r="$r" c="$c" file)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.  That seems to have worked and I would never have been able to figure out that that was the problem.  Sorry if this is a question that people ask alot, I tried searching for a solution before posting the quesiton, but couldn't come across anything.

Comment: as an aside, awk -F,     means the same thing as awk -F ","                     ?

Comment: I made a slight edit to your code above (not yet visible till peer reviewed).  I gave you credit for answer, please let me know if this didn't work for some reason. Thanks again

Comment: When you assign variables among the file name arguments as above then those variables are not set in the BEGIN section of your script which can take you by surprise later. For that reason and for clarity it's best to always use `awk -v var=val 'script' file1 file2` to assign variables UNLESS you want to change the value of variables in between opening files and THEN you'd do `awk 'script' var=val1 file1 var=val2 file2`

Comment: I know Ed, but if there is no `BEGIN` section, or variables are not needed in the `BEGIN` section, then I prefer to use variables this way, because (in my opinion) it makes the code easier to read and it gives a cleaner look than with the -v option..